# Write polynomial regression as one way ANOVA model

Tags: anova, linear-model, polynomial

I have difficulty understanding the relationship between polynomial regression and 1-way ANOVA model.

Suppose $x_i = (c_1,c_1,c_2,c_2,c_3,c_3)^T$

If:

$y_i = \gamma_0 + \gamma_1 x_i + \gamma_2 x_i^2 + e_i, i=1, ..., 6$

How to write this a one-way ANOVA model?

I know that $X=\tilde{X}T$, where $X$ is original design Matrix, $\tilde{X}$ is new design Matrix, $T$ is transformation Matrix which makes $c(X) = c(\tilde{X})$, so that the $\hat{Y}$ we are estimating remain the same for two models (difference appearance).

Answer (score -1):

ANOVAs are just special cases of regression using categorical predictors.

To do a one way ANOVA as a regression, simply dummy-code your predictor variable. So say you had a variable like gender (male, female, other). And your dependent was height.

You could dummy code with 2 dummy variables

Variable 1 (x1): male = 0 female = 1 and other = 0

Variable 2 (x2): male = 0 female = 0 and other = 1

And then your regression equation would be

Height = B0 + B1 (x1) + B2 (x2)

Then similar to contrasts in an ANOVA,

B0 is the mean of males.

B1 is the mean difference between males and females

B2 is the difference between males and other.